# why reactjs is returning GMT+ 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am wondering why the function `.format` in reactjs is returning the GMT + 1 even though in our JSON we have the right value.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why but you can use http://momentjs.com This package/plugin is best solution I think.

**Update**

http://momentjs.com/timezone/
Install moment-timezone package 
`yarn add moment-timezone`

And you can format your time with this package for example;

```
const dec = moment("2014-12-01T12:00:00Z");
dec.tz('Europe/Istanbul').format('ha z');
```

or add this code in your constructor / componentWillMount

```
moment().tz("Europe/Istanbul").format();
```

I I solved it like this.

Comment: That's exactly what we are using.

Comment: So, where you define your configs? For example I'm defining like import moment from 'moment'
import 'moment/locale/tr'; also define local / timezone in like componentWillMount  `moment.locale('tr');`

Comment: So far we do not have a config for moment. Should we add one?